# Cannot insert to my new table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have created a migration for ratings, and the table also working when i am entering phpmyadmin.

The problem is, i cannot figure out, how to write to the table? 
**I am running the code from "story" controller**

I am using this:

```
     $z = new Rating();
     $z->story_id = 10;
     $z->save();
     print_r($z);
```

My "ratings.php" model:

```
<?php
 class Rating extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'ratings';
  }
 ?>
```

Is there some place where i should notify laravel that new Rating() means my table "ratings"?

It doesn't seem like i have done the migration correctly, but i am completely new still, so hope someone can figure it out for me.

Comment: May be the lack of coffee, but looks ok to me. How is your Rating model defined?

Comment: i have not created model, how to do that? i have just created the table+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well instead of using the save() function for laravel you can use the insert() function

```
 Rating->insert_get_id(array('story_id' => '10'));
```

or

```
 $insert_id = Rating->insert_get_id(array('story_id' => '10'));
```

for insertion into table.This is much easy to use and I have used this in my whole project and so far I haven't face any problems.

Also if you have not created the model for rating table then go to the models folder under application folder and create a file name rating.php and inside the file write this:

```
class Rating extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = false;  
}
```

Also please note that table which you created in the phpmyadmin should have name of the form "ratings".

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: I have already done that with "ratings.php" check post again. i am running the code via my story controller, maybe it's the problem

Comment: rename the "ratings.php" file to "rating.php" in the model folder i think that should do the trick.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what the error is i.e. what is showing on the browser page.

Comment: I had to delete this  protected $table = 'ratings'; ... it works now

Comment: yes you don't require it because laravel automatically detects the table from the database if you have given the table name same as the model class name.This option is only used if you have given some other name to table(say "rate") and want it to be detect by this "Rating" class in the rating.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're doing. Are you trying to write into the table from php? Is Rating a sort of database connection class? You need to create a mysqli object to connect to the database, write a query, and get a result. For best security use a prepared statement. [Mysqli Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) Sorry if I'm off-base about your question, I'm just not positive about what it is.

Comment: It's using [Laravel's ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete), so no MySQLi required.